# Inner workings of `rand.Intn` function - GoLang

Tags: go, bit-manipulation, random-seed

Somehow, I happened to look at source code for Go on how it implements Random function when passed a length of array.

Here's the **calling code**

```
func randomFormat() string {
    formats := []string{
        "Hi, %v. Welcome!",
        "Great to see you, %v!",
        "Hail, %v! Well met!",
    }
    return formats[rand.Intn(len(formats))]
}
```

**Go Source code:** main part

```
func (r *Rand) Intn(n int) int {
    if n <= 0 {
        panic("invalid argument to Intn")
    }
    if n <= 1<<31-1 {
        return int(r.Int31n(int32(n)))
    }
    return int(r.Int63n(int64(n)))
}
```

**Go Source code:** reference part - Most of devs have this already on their machines or go repo.

```
// Int31n returns, as an int32, a non-negative pseudo-random number in [0,n).
// It panics if n <= 0.
func (r *Rand) Int31n(n int32) int32 {
    if n <= 0 {
        panic("invalid argument to Int31n")
    }
    if n&(n-1) == 0 { // n is power of two, can mask
        return r.Int31() & (n - 1)
    }
    max := int32((1 << 31) - 1 - (1<<31)%uint32(n))
    v := r.Int31()
    for v > max {
        v = r.Int31()
    }
    return v % n
}
// It panics if n <= 0.
func (r *Rand) Int63n(n int64) int64 {
    if n <= 0 {
        panic("invalid argument to Int63n")
    }
    if n&(n-1) == 0 { // n is power of two, can mask
        return r.Int63() & (n - 1)
    }
    max := int64((1 << 63) - 1 - (1<<63)%uint64(n))
    v := r.Int63()
    for v > max {
        v = r.Int63()
    }
    return v % n
}
func (r *Rand) Int31() int32 { return int32(r.Int63() >> 32) }
func (r *Rand) Int63() int64 { return r.src.Int63() }

type Source interface {
    Int63() int64
    Seed(seed int64)
}
```

I want to understand how the random function works encapsulating all inner functions. I am overwhelmed  by the code and if someone has to plan the steps out in plain English what would those be?

For example, I don't get the logic for doing minus 1 in

`if n <= 1<<31-1`

Then, I don't get any of the head or toe of `Int31n` function

```
  if n&(n-1) == 0 { // n is power of two, can mask
        return r.Int31() & (n - 1)
    }
    max := int32((1 << 31) - 1 - (1<<31)%uint32(n))
    v := r.Int31()
    for v > max {
        v = r.Int31()
    }
    return v % n
```

Comment: What specific operations are you unsure about? For example you're asking about the `Int63` method, but there is no logic in that method to comment on.

Comment: I asked the purpose of `Int63` but in general I want to understand how the random function works encapsulating all inner functions. There's a bit mask as well. I am overwhelmed  by the code.

Comment: Elaborated my questions.

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a question about algorithms than it is about Go, but there are some Go parts.  In any case I'll start with the algorithm issues.

#### Shrinking the range of a uniform random number generator

Suppose that we have a uniform-distribution random number generator that returns a number between, say, 0 and 7 inclusive.  That is, it will, over time, return about the same number of 0s, 1s, 2s, ..., 7s, but with no apparent pattern between them.

Now, if we *want* a uniformly distributed random number between 0 and 7, this thing is perfect.  That's what it returns.  We just use it.  But what if we want a uniformly distributed random number between 0 and 6 instead?

We could write:

```
func randMod7() int {
    return generate() % 7
}
```

so that if `generate()` returns 7 (which it has a 1 out of 8 chance of doing), we convert that value to zero.  But then we'll get zero back 2 out of 8 times, instead of 1 out of 8 times.  We'll get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 back 1 out of 8 times, and zero 2 out of 8 times, on average: once for each actual zero, and once for each 7.

What we need to do, then, is *throw away* any occurrences of 7:

```
func randMod7() int {
    for {
        if i := generate() < 7 {
            return i
        }
        // oops, got 7, try again
    }
}
```

Now, if we had a uniform-random-number-generator named `generate()` that returned a value between 0 and (say) 11 (12 possible values) and we wanted a value between 0 and 3 (four possible values), we *could* just use `generate() % 4`, because the 12 possible results would fall into 3 groups of four with equal probability.  If we wanted a value between 0 and 5 inclusive, we could use `generate() % 6`, because the 12 possible results would fall into two groups of 6 with equal probability.  In fact, all we need to do is examine the prime factorization of the *range of our uniform number generator* to see what moduli work.  The factors of 12 are 2, 2, 3; so 2, 3, 4, and 6 all work here.  Any other modulus, such as `generate() % 10`, produce a biased result: 0 and 1 occur 2 out of 12 times, but 2 through 9 occur 1 out of 12 times.  (Note: `generate() % 12` also works, but is kind of pointless.)

In our particular case, we have two different uniform random number generators available.  One, `Int31()`, produces values between 0 and 0x7fffffff (2147483647 decimal, or 2<sup>31</sup> - 1, or `1<<31 - 1`) inclusive.  The other, `Int63()`, produces values between 0 and 0x7fffffffffffffff (9223372036854775807, or 2<sup>63</sup> - 1, or `1<<63 - 1`).  These are ranges that hold 2<sup>31</sup> and 2<sup>63</sup> values respectively, and hence their prime factorization is 31 2s, or 63 2s.

What this means is that we can compute `Int31()` mod 2<sup>`k`</sup>, for any integer `k` in zero to 31 inclusive, without messing up our uniformity.  With `Int63()`, we can do the same with `k` ranging all the way up to 63.

#### Introducing the computer

Now, mathematically-and-computer-ly speaking, given any nonnegative integer *n* in [`0`..`0x7ffffff`] or [`0`..`0x7fffffffffffffff`], and a non-negative integer *k* in the right range (no more than 31 or 63 respectively), computing that integer *n* mod 2<sup>*k*</sup> produces the *same result* as computing that integer and doing a bit-mask operation with *k* bits set.  To *get* that number of set bits, we want to take `1<<k` and subtract 1.  If `k` is, say, 4, we get 1<<4 or 16.  Subtracting 1, we get 15, or 0xf, which has four 1 bits in it.

So:

```
n % (1 << k)
```

and:

```
n & (1<<k - 1)
```

*produce the same result*.  Concretely, when `k==4`, this is `n%16` or `n&0xf`.  When `k==5` this is `n%32` or `n&0x1f`.  Try it for `k==0` and `k==63`.

#### Introducing Go-the-language

We're now ready to consider doing all of this in Go.  We note that `int` (plain, unadorned `int`) is guaranteed to be able to hold values between -2147483648 and +2147483647 (-0x80000000 through +0x7fffffff) respectively.  It *may* extend all the way to -0x8000000000000000 through +0x7ffffffffffffff.

Meanwhile, `int32` always handles the smaller range and `int64` always handles the larger range.  The plain `int` is a different *type* from these other two, but implements the *same range* as one of the two.  We just don't know which one.

Our `Int31` implementation returns a uniformly distributed random number in the `0..0x7ffffff` range.  (It does this by returning the upper 32 bits of `r.Int63()`, though this is an implementation detail.)  Our `Int63` implementation returns a uniformly distributed random number in the `0..0x7ffffffffffffff` range.

The `Intn` function you show here:

```golang
func (r *Rand) Intn(n int) int {
    if n <= 0 {
        panic("invalid argument to Intn")
    }
    if n <= 1<<31-1 {
        return int(r.Int31n(int32(n)))
    }
    return int(r.Int63n(int64(n)))
}
```

just picks one of the two functions, based on the value of `n`: if it's less than or equal to `0x7fffffff` (`1<<31 - 1`), the result fits in `int32`, so it uses `int32(n)` to convert `n` to `int32`, calls `r.Int31n`, and converts the result back to `int`.  Otherwise, the value of `n` exceeds `0x7fffffff`, implying that `int` has the larger range and we must use the larger-range generator, `r.Int63n`.  The rest is the same except for types.

The code *could* just do:

```
return int(r.Int63n(int64(n)))
```

every time, but on 32-bit machines, where 64-bit arithmetic may be slow, this might be slow.  (There's a lot of *may* and *might* here and if you were writing this yourself today, you should start by profiling / benchmarking the code.  The Go authors *did* do this, though this was many years ago; *at that time* it was worth doing this fancy stuff.)

#### More bit-manipulation

The insides of both functions `Int31n` and `Int63n` are quite similar; the main difference is the *types* involved, and then in a few places, the maximum values.  Again, the reason for this is at least partly historical: on some (mostly old now) computers, the `Int63n` variant is significantly slower than the `Int32n` variant.  (In some non-Go language, we might write these as *generics* and then have the compiler generate a type-specific version automatically.)  So let's just look at the `Int63` variant:

```golang
func (r *Rand) Int63n(n int64) int64 {
    if n <= 0 {
        panic("invalid argument to Int63n")
    }
    if n&(n-1) == 0 { // n is power of two, can mask
        return r.Int63() & (n - 1)
    }
    max := int64((1 << 63) - 1 - (1<<63)%uint64(n))
    v := r.Int63()
    for v > max {
        v = r.Int63()
    }
    return v % n
}
```

The argument `n` has type `int64`, so that its value will not exceed 2<sup>63</sup>-1 or `0x7fffffffffffffff` or 9223372036854775807.  But it could be negative, and negative values won't work right, so the first thing we do is test for that and panic if so.  We also panic if the input is zero (this is something of a choice, but it's useful to note it now).

Next we have the `n&(n-1) == 0` test.  This is a test for powers of two, with one slight flaw, and it works in many languages (those that have bit-masking):

- A power of two is always represented as a single set bit, in the binary representation of a number.  For instance, 2 itself is 00000001<sub>2</sub>, 4 is 00000010<sub>2</sub>, 8 is 00000100<sub>2</sub>, and so on, through 128 being 10000000<sub>2</sub>.  (Since I only "drew" eight bits this series maxes out at 128.)
- Subtracting 1 from that number causes a borrow: that bit goes to zero, and all the lesser bits become 1.  For instance, 10000000<sub>2</sub> - 1 is 01111111<sub>2</sub>.
- AND-ing these two together produces zero if there was just the single bit set initially.  If not—for instance, if we have the value 130 or 10000010<sub>2</sub> initially, subtracting 1 produces 10000001<sub>2</sub>—there's no borrow out of the *top* bit, so the top bit is set in both inputs and therefore is set in the AND-ed result.

The slight flaw is that if the initial value *is* zero, then we have `0-1`, which produces all-1s; `0&0xffffffffffffffff` is zero too, but zero is not an integer power of two.  (2<sup>0</sup> is 1, not 0.)  This minor flaw is not important for our purpose here, because we already made sure to panic for this case: it just doesn't happen.

Now we have the most complicated line of all:

```golang
    max := int64((1 << 63) - 1 - (1<<63)%uint64(n))
```

The recurring `63`s here are because we have a value range going from zero to 2<sup>63</sup>-1.  `1<<63 - 1` is (still, again, always) 9223372036854775807 or `0x7fffffffffffffff`.  Meanwhile, `1<<63`, without 1 subtracted from it, is 9223372036854775808 or `0x8000000000000000`.  **This value does not fit into `int64`** but it *does* fit into `uint64`.  So if we turn `n` into a `uint64`, we can compute `uint64(9223372036854775808) % uint64(n)`, which is what the `%` expression does.  By using `uint64` for *this* calculation, we ensure that it doesn't overflow.

But: what is this calculation all about?  Well, go back to our example with a `generate()` that produces values in [0..7].  When we wanted a number in [0..5], we had to *discard* both 6 and 7.  That's what we're going for here: we want to find the value above which we should *discard* values.

If we were to take 8%6, we'd get 2.  8 is one bigger than the maximum that our 3-bit `generate()` would generate.  8%6 == 2 is the number of "high values" that we have to discard: 8-2 = 6 and we want to discard values that are 6 or more.  Subtract 1 from this, and we get 7-2 = 5; we can *accept* numbers in this input range, from 0 to 5 inclusive.

So, this somewhat fancy calculation for setting `max` is just a way to find out what the *maximum* value we *like* is.  Values that are greater than `max` need to be tossed out.

This particular calculation works nicely even if `n` is much less than our generator returns.  For instance, suppose we had a four-bit generator, returning values in the [0..15] range, and we wanted a number in [0..2].  Our `n` is therefore 3 (to indicate that we want a number in `[0..2]`).  We compute 16%3 to get 1.  We then take 15 (one less than our maximum output value) - 1 to get 14 as our maximum *acceptable* value.  That is, we would allow numbers in [0..14], but *exclude* 15.

With a 63-bit generator returning values in [0..9223372036854775807], and n==3, we would set max to 9223372036854775805.  That's what we want: it throws out the two biasing values, 9223372036854775806 and 9223372036854775807.

The remainder of the code simply does that:

```golang
    v := r.Int63()
    for v > max {
        v = r.Int63()
    }
    return v % n
```

We pick one `Int63`-range number.  If it exceeds `max`, we pick another one and check again, until we pick one that is in the [0..max] range, inclusive of `max`.

Once we get a number that *is* in range, we use `% n` to *shrink* the range if needed.  For instance, if the range is [0..2], we use `v % 3`.  If v is (say) 14, 14%3 is 2.  Our actual max is, again, 9223372036854775805, and whatever v is, between 0 and that, v%3 is between 0 and 2 and remains uniformly distributed, with no slight bias to 0 and 1 (9223372036854775806 would give us that one extra `0`, and 9223372036854775807 would give us that one extra `1`).

(Now repeat the above for `int32` and `32` and `1<<32`, for the `Int31` function.)